# What is the difference between scope and encapsulation? (C++)

Tags: c++

Picking up programming after like 8 years of... not programming (starting college soon, brushing up on old knowledge).

What is the difference between scope and encapsulation? They seem to be rather similar.

Comment: Scope is the area within a program where a variable or object lives.  Encapsulation determines how variables and objects will grouped together.

Comment: I recommend posting this question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

A **scope** is an area within a program within which *automatic variables* may be created and at the end of which they are *automatically* destroyed. Examples are a function body or the code-block of a *for-loop*.

**Scopes** may enclose one another and variables in an outer **scope** may, or may not, be accessible by code in an inner **scope**.

For example the **global scope** encloses all other **scopes** and variables created in the **global scope** are *visible* to all other **scopes** (according to various name resolution rules).

Therefore **scope** also refers to the *visibility* of objects that can be accessed from a given point in the program.

There are different types of **scope** each with their own *visibility* rules, for example **class scope** refers to the visibility of *member variables* and *member functions* to the *member functions* of a *class object*.

For more detailed definitions see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

**Encapsulation** is when you hide the specific data that makes up an object and focus only on how the object behaves according to its function interface. In `C++` this *data hiding* is primarily achieved by marking the data as `private` or `protected` rendering it inaccessible from outside the *structure* within which it is defined.

Comment: There's a second meaning of **scope**: relating to the grouping of content within namespaces and class/struct/union names.  (May also help to mention that *hiding* is done with `private` and `protected`).

Comment: @TonyD Yes, I was trying to keep it simple but the more I thought about your comment the more complex I realized the subject is. I know the basic principles about *scope* but I'm not an expert on all of the details.

Comment: agreed - any concise conceptual introduction/overview must ignore small details.  I really like your first cut, just thought it worth pointing out the types of scopes *outside* functions and unrelated to automatic variables.  By not leading into the second meaning with "There's a second meaning", or prefixing both with "there're a compile-time namespacing sense of scope, and a runtime flow-control sense of scope", you've ended up implying all statements apply to all scopes - e.g. first paragraph implies automatic variables can be placed in global and namespace scope.  Tricky!

Comment: Still, just having enough detail here to introduce the difference is good - the OP can go off and do further reading (your cppreference link's nice).

Answer (score 1):

They *are* similar.

Scope is about defining the lifetime of objects (loosely related to the "lexical", or code-wise, boundaries of the place in which they were declared), whereas encapsulation is all about controlling who can access those objects during that lifetime.